# SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I am making a Java Application and I need to connect to a MySQL Database.
I am using snippets I used earlier on my desktop (I am using my laptop at the moment) and worked. Now, on my laptop, it wont function as it should. Here is the code:

```
public void connect() {
    String connectTo = "jdbc:mysql//" + settings.getConfig().getString("mysql.ip") + ":" + settings.getConfig().getString("mysql.port") + "/" + settings.getConfig().getString("mysql.db");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectTo, settings.getConfig().getString("mysql.username"), settings.getConfig().getString("mysql.password"));
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to the database");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace I am getting: http://pastebin.com/bGhkqWGg

If you need anything else, just ask :)

Thanks already,
Guus Huizen

**FIX:**

I added an : after the jdbc:mysql and it started working, I found this on the internet and I hope this will save someone's frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MySQL JDBC driver to your JVM's classpath.

If you use Maven, then just add a depedency to [mysql-connector-java](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6).
If not, download the provided jar and add `-cp path-to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar`.

Comment: Where do I add that line?

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency to classpath, if you are using maven as build tool. Otherwise download    [mysql jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar) and add it to class path.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I added it as dependency in IntelliJ, but still is not working. Where do I add it to the class path?

Comment: Go to the Project Structure, click on Modules, and click on your Module. Choose the "Dependencies" tab. Click the "+" button on the right-hand side and select "Jars or directories..." Add the directory(files) you want (note you can multi-select) and click OK.

Comment: Simply copying the jar to your project directory won't help. You need to add that jar as library.  Could you please post your module settings?

Comment: Can you please download the jar from link i shared and use it.? I guess you are not using correct jar.

Comment: I did, I only renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

It says your project cannot locate the path of mysql `Driver`. Download `mysql-connector-java.jar` and add it into your project library. Use following url to download mysql Driver.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjar.htm

Comment: what is the mysql driver using?. what is the IDE ? try clean and build project

Comment: Don't know what you mean by 'using', But I am using IntelliJ. I will clean and build project now, gimme a sec.

Comment: IDE means NetBeans, Eclipse, InteliJ or other?